# The package source named 'NuGet' is either invalid or not available

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, nuget, nuget-package

I have installed Nuget 1.2 yesterday, and today, while I was trying to install Entity Framework package, I have encountered the following problem in the Package Manager Console:

> PM> install-package entityframework
>   Install-Package : The package source named 'NuGet official package source   [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669]' is either
>   invalid or not available and thus is currently unreachable.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  entityframework
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I can surft the internet and I don't think anything is preventing Visual Studio to access the internet.

Comment: Try opening a browser and navigating to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669 . Do you get redirected to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/ or do you get a error? A proxy my be blocking the FWLINK service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, there *was* something that was preventing Visual Studio from accessing the internet. Seems like VS had some problems with my proxy server.
So I used a solution that has been introduced in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/visual-studio-2010-cannot-connect-for-any-online-resource/3151916#3151916) and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to my setup. However, i found that VS 2010 uses proxy settings from Internet Explorer. I have removed proxy settings from IE and it was successfully connecting.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this problem permanently, a fix from Microsoft must be used

This is the name of the file KB2581019(VS10SP1-KB2581019-x86.exe)

While this link is active you can download path correction for it.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=38654

It's solved!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.