# Cannot install .Vsix package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I have troubles with .vsix installation.

If I launch the .vsix from the explorer, instead of suggesting me to install the package, I get the same ouput as `Vsixintaller.exe /?` (it displays the command line usage).

I also tried to run the following command line :

> VSIXInstaller.exe /skuname:Pro "fullpathto\NuGet.Tools.vsix"

Same output (command line usage is displayed).

What can be wrong ?

I'm suspecting a wrong registry registration, but I couldn't find the source of the problem.

Here is what I have in my registry :

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix] @="Microsoft Visual
>   Studio Extension"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix\DefaultIcon]
>   @="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\MSEnv\VSFileHandler.dll,-221"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix\Shell]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix\Shell\Open]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix\Shell\Open\Command]
>   @="\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe\" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.vsix] "Content Type"="application/vsix"
>   @="VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.vsix\OpenWithProgids]
>   "VisualStudio.Launcher.vsix"=""

Any idea ?

PS: my computer is running W2K8 R2 x64, and I use VS 2010 Pro.

I cannot use Visual Studio integrated extension manager because of a proxy server not working with the gallery (don't know why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ... finally found the issue.

VSix Installer does not seems to be able to install from a network share.
With local copies of vsix, it worked. Strange.

Comment: see this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/cannot-connect-to-any-online-resource

Comment: It didn't worked for me either, it is prompting me as " path to vsic file is invalid or you dont have required permissions" Do i have to run this under administrator role?