# Cannot search for online exensions because an error occured while trying to contact the server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, proxy, avr-studio5

My problem is this error

```
"Cannot search for online exensions because an error occured while trying to contact the server"
```

in extension manager > online extensions.

I know 2 solutions from this thread [Cannot connect to any online resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/visual-studio-2010-cannot-connect-for-any-online-resource/9535140#9535140):

1. Adding `**servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"**`
   I tried this. But doesnt work.

2.Add:-

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
<proxy proxyaddress="http://your.proxyserver.ip:port"/>
</defaultProxy>
```

I want to implement this but I dont know what how to fill **<http://your.proxyserver.ip:port>**

I did a proxy check and i got this

```
"
The proxy host has ip address 182.237.151.96

The proxy server has announced itself as 1.1 fivenet5.netsolutioninc.com:8102 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)

The proxy informs us that the client host ip address was 182.237.151.96
"
```

Can someone help pls. I m a rookie in this.

Thank you for reading this

Comment: Can't you simply browse to http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ outside visual studio?

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to search for VS extension from inside VS, and it doesn't works. So browsing visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com outside VS require less time that making it work inside VS :-) It's just a comment, it's not a solution :-)

Comment: oh lol :). but it doent work. I want to install ankhsvn extension. Tried installing standalone but studio doesnt recog it. Any other soln?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok 
**For your question**:
  - I don't know where did you get the proxy information that you provided, but if it's right, you should put http://fivenet5.netsolutioninc.com:8102 as you proxy.

- I was with the same problem as you and setting up *servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"* worked for me.

**For what I think is your problem reading you comments**:
  - After install AnhkSVN if you have Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, you must set it as the source control manager. 
    Inside Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control.
      From there, select AnkhSVN in *current source control plug-in* (normally its None or Visual Studio Team Foundation Server).
    Restart Visual Studio and everything should work.

Hope it helps