# VS2010 and proxy settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, proxy, ftp, proxy-server

**Forgot to mention that I'm using `FTP` for open web site**

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on a web project.
The problem come when I need to work in an office where internet connection is done via a `Proxy server`.
I've tried [any kind of suggested changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/visual-studio-2010-cannot-connect-for-any-online-resource) to  `devenv.exe.config` but using a TCPViewer I can see that any request from devenv.exe aren't done trough the proxy but directly and I can't open the remote website.

It seems that VS2010 doesn't read the configuration setting.
Someone had same issue? It's possible to resolve it?

Edit:

The proxy is wingate and this is the part of config I used:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true"> // Tried with/without 'usedefaultCredential' Wingate use  IP matching for authorize connections
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://Myproxyserverip:8888"/>
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" /> // Tried with and without this.
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: It does read the config. Your modifications are probably not correct. Please specify the proxy server you are dealing with.

Comment: @leppie Proxy it's Wingate and port it's 8888 see my edit

Comment: Can you provide the modifications you applied to the config file as well?

Comment: which remote website are you trying to open ?

Comment: @lysergic-acid It's irrilevant. If I'm not behind a proxy I can open web site without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the only solution it's to NOT use a proxy server to connect to the internet for open a web site via FTP with VS2010.
It seems that Visual Studio 2010 ( also Express version) not use proxy setting for FTP connections.

I didn't be able to find any information or issue for this stuff in microsoft.com site and connect.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the solution (at least for me) is to set an user wide or system wide environment variable. I set this two envirionment variables:

> HTTP_PROXY
>
> HTTPS_PROXY

Here's a screenshot:

[image: environment variables]

**If VS2010 is already open, close it and reload it so can parse the environment variables.**

ps. I'm using cntlm as proxy.

Comment: I Have to test it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

#### Just a suggestion to try...

You can disable the "ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace and Test Impact". To disable: Go to Test » Edit Test Settings » (select the current active test settings), select Data and Diagnostics and disable the mentioned setting.

[image: VSTS proxy settings]

Comment: mmhh Is not my case.. I've 'No Test Settings Available' in: Test>>Edit Test Setting.

Comment: Oh okay. But it is VS TS Right?

Comment: No just Visual Studio 2010 pro or ultimate as I'm a freelance developper.

Comment: Oh okay... Lemme find any other way, and will update. Ok? Coz I too faced same problem, but I am using VSTS2010! :)

Comment: This was the fix for us - thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it may help someone.  Most client software uses HTTP for things, and uses wininet.  If you use wininet to retrieve and FTP URL, the WinInet stack does the FTP.

If however you specify a proxy, then for FTP, WinInet reverts to HTTP, and hands off the work of the FTP to the proxy.  So, when you specify a proxy for FTP, it needs to be the same proxy as for HTTP - same port number.  A really common mistake is to presume that the client needs to use the FTP proxy instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections Tab > LAN settings**

Setup your proxy there. Then in your Visual Studio installation go to:

`D:\programs\VS2010\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` and add this config:

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```