# Can't Install Local Help: 407 Proxy Authentication Error

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, visual-studio-2013

Installation of Visual Studio local help (Books Online) fails with a 407 Proxy Authentication Required error.

The problem here is that if you are behind a not-terribly-friendly corporate firewall or proxy, you may have a hard time installing local help in Visual Studio 2013.

When I fired up the Help Viewer v2.1, I would initially see the list of help topics that might be installed. Instead I'd get a notification that errors had occurred. Drilling down into that, I'd see that our corporate proxy had handed back a 407 Proxy Authentication Required response asking for NTLM authentication. Apparently, the Help Viewer isn't smart enough to respond intelligently handle this ordinary HTTP response.

The question is: how to work around this problem, since getting the network gods to set up a more transparent proxy seems...unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question, [Visual Studio Error: (407: Proxy Authentication Required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717815/visual-studio-error-407-proxy-authentication-required) (related, but not the same problem) helped lead me to the solution, as did this conversation:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65c07e43-b652-496e-acbd-4d98861d527e/cannot-install-local-help-in-visual-studio-11?forum=vssetup

There are, apparently, 3 different processes involved in getting help installed for VS 2013:

- The Microsoft Help Viewer (`HlpViewer.exe`)
- The Microsoft Help Content Manager (`HlpCtntMgr.exe`)
- The BITS service (*Background Intelligent Transfer Service*)

The above threads will lead you to monkeying with the config file for the help viewr, but that's insufficient to fix the problem. You will need to do the following:

1. Navigate to the help viewer's install directory (default location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.1`).
2. Create or edit the file `HlpViewer.exe.config` so that it has a `<system.net>` element that looks like this:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.net>
       <settings>
         <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
       </settings>
       <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
         <proxy
           bypassonlocal="True"
           proxyaddress="http://your-proxy-server:80/"
         />
       </defaultProxy>
     </system.net>
   </configuration>
   ```

   Depending on the vagaries of your proxy configuration, you might or might not need the `<proxy>` element.
3. Do the same for `HlpCtntMgr.exe.config`.
4. BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) has a configuration value, `UseLmCompat` that tells it when to send NTLM authentication credentials. From [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/aa362781),

   > The registry value is a DWORD. The following table lists the possible values for
   >   UseLMCompat:
   >
   > ```
   > Value Description
   > ----- -----------
   >   0   BITS will send implicit credentials whenever the server prompts
   >         for NTLM or Kerberos credentials.
   >   1   BITS will send implicit credentials only if the client computer's
   >         LMCompatibilityLevel registry value is greater than or equal to 2.
   >         Prior to BITS 1.5:  Not supported
   >   2   BITS will send implicit credentials only if the application called
   >         the SetCredentials method.
   >         Prior to BITS 2.0:  Not supported
   > ```

   The default cofiguration appears to be `2`. You'll probably need to modify that in
   the registry at

   ```
   HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/BITS/UseLmCompat
   ```

   where you'll want that value to be `0`, so it will provide credentials on request.

   **NOTE:** Since Microsoft, in its infinite wisdom, has blessed us with, not one, but *two* registries (32-bit and 64-bit), you'll need to make the above change twice, using the appropriate instances of `regedit.exe` located at

   - **32-bit:** `C:\Windows\regedit.exe`
   - **64-bit:** `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe`
5. Having done that, you'll need to bounce BITS. You can do that by rebooting your machine, or via the Services control panel (`services.msc`), where it's listed under the name `Background Intelligent Transfer Service`.

At this point, you should be good to go.