# PhoneRTC Cordova Plugin Won't Install in Visual Studio Cordova Projects

Tags: cordova, webrtc, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, phonertc

In both Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015 Preview when trying to add the custom plugin PhoneRTC by inputting the .git URL the loading bar keeps going on forever. Adding plugins in VS is done by right clicking config.xml then View Designer -> Plugins. I also tried installing the cordova opentok plugin the same way and it caused VS to crash; however, I have successfully installed other plugins from github.

I'm not sure what causes these problems but it isn't possible to manually add the plugins. I've tried from the Windows command line and methods related to similar (But not the same) issues people have had with no success.

It's hard to say if this is the fault of Visual Studio or the plugins themselves (Since many work fine). I would say that part of it is the Cordova integration in VS because for instance I was able to add opentok via the command line to a project created by cordova on the command line. I'm looking for the cause of this in certain plugins. I think it's a problem with the plugin.xml file but I can't be sure.

Either there's a bug in Cordova for VS or plugin developers need to update their files to work with VS importing. This post is to serve the purpose of possibly getting some answers or at least to help alert the plugin or Cordova devs to this issue. I would love to start using WebRTC in Cordova but I want to use VS for it's superior debugging and emulation and I can't do anything WebRTC without importing plugins. I did open up an issue for this on PhoneRTC's Github and the Cordova bug tracker.

Thanks to anyone who might be able to help.

Comment: What's the Git URL? I can try to repro and open a bug.

Comment: PhoneRTC doesn't import and is https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git . OpenTok causes VS to crash when importing and is at https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok.git . Of course I'd like to use PhoneRTC because the whole setup is free. At this point though neither (and those are the only two you would consider using for Cordova WebRTC) will import in VS.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I can confirm your reports on the released builds. Currently getting the latest internal build to see if we fixed it already, I'll open bugs if not.

Comment: The second repros on our internal build and I opened a bug. The first took a long time (about a minute) to add but I think that was because it pulls down 345MB of data. It did finish successfully. I didn't wait long enough on the released build to verify if it would complete but I bet it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the PhoneRtc plugin github repository as [zip](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/archive/master.zip), unzip to a folder and install the plugin from there using the local method.

This will, for example, circumvent [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717815/visual-studio-error-407-proxy-authentication-required) in Visual Studio like connect to the internet behind a proxy with username and passwords. It takes some time to complete though but it will complete eventually.