# Visual Studio "No connection could be made because target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I tried to run a solution through Visual studio on my local machine. I get the webpage to appear and receive the error on the page: Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

The page that loads is http://localhost:5009/ and when I try localhost:8888 I get "This page can't be displayed"

Thought it might be firewall related so I opened port 8888 but still the issue occurs

someone suggested that this might be an IIS Express issue that Visual Studio 2013 hides but I couldn't find the config for it.

Thanks

Comment: Run `netstat -ano` from the command-line on the server machine to see if anything is actually listening on port 8888. If not, it's a server configuration issue.

Comment: You're probably configured to point to Fiddler but Fiddler isn't running. So either some proxy settings need to be updated or you need to start Fiddler. If it's not proxy settings on the machine, there could be proxy entries in <system.net> in a config file.

Comment: I am facing following problem in wpf project.

[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  Unable to connect to the remote server
  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: this solution solved my problem .

Answer (score 22):

I had same problem. It was configuration to point to Fiddler. I removed the fiddler configuration in the web.config file and problem solved.

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Comment: Same think for me, someone enabled fiddler for testing and forgot to remove the entry when finished.

Comment: Same with fiddler. I had it on earlier but the issue continued after closing it. Restarting my machine fixed my issue.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old but I would like to share what did to resolve this problem. I found out that the cause of this is from the Internet Explorer's Proxy connection is enabled.

You can go to IE > Settings > Internet Options

Then Internet Options dialog will open.

Go to Connections tab and look for LAN settings.

From there, if you see the "Use a proxy server for your LAN (These settings will not apply to dial-up or VPN connections)." checked, uncheck it and press OK.

then that error will be removed.

I hope this helps on other readers experiencing this kind of issue.

Answer (score 8):

Also check machine.config under

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config and/or
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

i had this set by fiddler:

```
<system.net>  
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

remove this xml part. If it does not take effect restart your computer (i needed it in my case).

Comment: nailed it, thank you. Had proxy set for fiddler in web.config

Comment: I deleted these line in both files and it worked for me as well. To just let you know, I had to restart my computer.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem due to a Fiddler upgrade. I just unticked "Enable IPv6".

[image]

Comment: I should add that you need to actually run Fiddler as well

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me. Fiddler wasn't even open at the time when I was getting this error.

Comment: It works when Fiddler is running, if not, it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

For who live in IRAN: you need to turn on your Proxy/VPN server.

Comment: What is the port mentioned in the error ? How can configure not to use any proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I changed the configured port number for my website. The first run on Firefox or Chrome would work, but the error would appear in the Output window on subsequent runs and the page would never load. It seems the browser holds on to the port number after the debugging stops, so it cannot launch again.

The solution for me was to start running it in Internet Explorer. That is the one browser that consistently opens and closes the port appropriately in tandem with VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers I found that Fiddler enabled Proxy for me as well, I canceled it from here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG0Ci.png)

Answer (score 0):

**My case**

I had same issue. It was because we call the **service or Url** with https.

[image: This is my Setting File]

```
objEQPCareManager.Url = SettingsValues.ServicePath+"/EQP_Care_manager.asmx";
```

Error Message is :-
[image]

### Solution##

---

I simply removed the **'s'** from ***https*** then it works fine in my case.

---