# TFS PowerTools Proxy Authentication Required HTTP code 407

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools

Am behind a corporate proxy server and when attempting to use TFS Power Tools 2015 to view history or indeed any operation from the explorer extension I get a **"HTTP code 407: Proxy Authorization Required"** when connecting to Visual Studio Team Services online @ xyz.visualstudio.com.

Encountered a similar issue with VS2015 but resolved it by using the default proxy setting as mention in an answer in this question [Visual Studio Error: (407: Proxy Authentication Required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717815/visual-studio-error-407-proxy-authentication-required?wb48617274=83767D5D)

Tried applying the same setting to TF.exe.config and TFPT.EXE.config but got no joy, the error still occurs. Any hints or tips as to how to resolve would be appreciated!

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just apply the setting to TF.exe.config and TFPT.EXE.config file, this setting should be only applicable to TF.exe and TFPT.exe. Call them from Command Line to check if the setting works.

When you view history or do other operation from Windows Explorer Extension, it calls "TfsCommandRunnerSvr.exe" which locates in TFS Power Tools installation folder. Try to create a "TfsCommandRunnerSvr.exe.config" file in the folder and apply the setting to it to see if it can works.