# Visual Studio 2015 "forgets" Proxy Authentication

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, proxy

my problem is that every time I start VS, I see
`HTTP code 407: Proxy Authentication Required`
in the Output window.

This is despite me having entered the credentials AND having agreed to remember the credentials.

So now I have to go to Team->Manage Connections. This opens Team Explorer with a "Manage Connections" link. That gives me a window where my Team Foundation Server is already configured but under Team Project Collections I see the 407 error. Below that I need to click Switch User. This gives me a login promt where --- and here comes the funny part --- I just type the first letter of my login and click on the suggested name, which autofills username and password and after that I get a succesful connection.

So WHY does not this work automatically? All information is obviously already there! Is this a known bug or am I missing some further options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Error: (407: Proxy Authentication Required)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717815/visual-studio-error-407-proxy-authentication-required)

Comment: No, I've read the linked discussion before. There the solution does not match my scenario. In particular "3. There will be a failure notice on screen and a link to enter your credentials. Click it and enter them." does not apply. Updates work just fine for me

Comment: Forgot to mention that when I click on Manage Connections in the Output window I get:             TF205020: Could not connect to server ‘*****.visualstudio.com\*****’. This server was used in your last session, but it might be offline or unreachable. Confirm that the server is available on the network. To attempt to connect again, or to a different server, click ‘Connect To Team Foundation Server’ in Team Explorer or the Team menu.

The server returned the following error: HTTP code 407: Proxy Authentication Required