# Error 407 after computer name change: Visual studio Team Services / TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

My infrastructure changed the name of my computer. When I opened visual studio to connect to TFS, I got a message saying that "Workspace 'X' does not reside on this computer.  If this computer was recently renamed, the workspace may be updated by running tf workspaces /updateComputerName:oldComputerName.

So I ran this for my local workspace and it worked just fine.  Now I'm trying to run it for a workspace that is connected to visualstudio.com and I'm getting a 'HTTP code 407: Proxy Authentication Required' error.

I have already made some changes to my vsenv.exe.config for proxy as below.  I also tried to add the same thing to tf.exe.config, with no luck.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Anyone have any ideas how to get around this proxy issue?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy server which requires credentials of your TFS connection?

Comment: Yes I'm behind a corporate proxy server

Answer (score 0):

This error usually  occurs when VS tried to do an automatic update but was stopped by the proxy. You can try below way to prompt for credentials:

> **WORKAROUND:**
>
> 1. Open **TOOLS>Extensions & Updates**
> 2. Click on **Updates...** in the left-hand menu
> 3. There will be a failure notice on screen and a link to enter your credentials. Click it and enter them.
> 4. Close the Extension manager.
> 5. Click **TEAM>Connect to TFS server...**
> 6. Enter the address and connect to TFS

More detail info and ways, please take a look at this similar question: [Visual Studio Error: (407: Proxy Authentication Required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717815/visual-studio-error-407-proxy-authentication-required)