# Azure deploy issues

Tags: c#, azure, azure-deployment

When I would like to deplopy my cloud service to azure, I get this error anytime:

```
Warning: Unable to connect to the remote serve
```

http://snag.gy/KdzQT.jpg

I've double checked everything. The cloud service is exist, the subscription is ok. I tried making a fully new cloud service, even with a "empty" cloud wcf application, non of them worked.

If a click a package (not the publish) option in the visual studio, and go to the management portal, and upload a package, everything just fine, it would be ok, but i would like to enable intellitrace for the deployment, and i could see any option to do it that way. I can enable it only trough vs deploy wizard.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks, 
T

Comment: I have a Cloud Service hosting an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app. It has always deployed OK to my MSDN Azure subscription, but now I come to deploy to another subscription (to be the "Live" account), of which I am co-admin, I get a number of 'Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server' messages on each deployment. Sometimes it gives up and sometimes it gets through and finishes the deployment.

Comment: Have you find solution for this issue? I start to have the same for all my subscriptions!!!

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you enable intellitrace from the Visual Studio deployment wizard, it changes your cscfg/csdef files.  So you can enable intellitrace in this wizard, then cancel the wizard, and then do your normal publish process via the portal.  This should let you work around the issue while you get Visual Studio working.

As for Visual Studio not connecting, it is most likely the result of a proxy server in your network.  Visual Studio won't automatically get your proxy settings from IE so you will need to create a devenv.exe.config file.  See [Cannot connect to any online resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/visual-studio-2010-cannot-connect-for-any-online-resource) or http://gurustop.net/blog/2010/08/10/visual-studio-2010-extension-manager-online-gallery-behind-internet-proxy/ for more info.

Comment: I'm having the same issue sometimes, it's not related to proxy because I don't have one. After a while it works. Here is my output: 10:45:59 - Uploading Package...
10:46:42 - Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server
10:47:39 - Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server
10:48:37 - Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server
10:49:35 - Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server
10:50:34 - Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server
10:51:32 - Warning: Unable to connect to the remote server
10:51:51 - Creating...