# Visual Studio 2013 Extension Manager "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: visual-studio

I have a little problem with Visual Studio 2013. The extension manager is unable to connect to the remote server. I think it is error of configuration, because the final address it is Localhost :

[Visual Studio 2013 Extensions Manager problem http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/803808BugVS2012ExtensionsManager.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/803808BugVS2012ExtensionsManager.png)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to any online resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/cannot-connect-to-any-online-resource)

Comment: Thank, but it don't work. Again the above message. a other information, I don't use proxy.

Comment: check your port number

Comment: The issue is solved, but I have no idea what is the solution. Thank for your help.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and have been unable to find a solution. I've gone so far as to uninstall Fiddler and Skype, thinking they were occupying the port, but the problem persists. Does anyone have a solution to this?