# Visual Studio cannot connect to any online ressource

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to run VS 2013 Premium (Update 4) on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

The problem I have is, that I can't connect to any ressource in the internet.
It doesn't matter wheater I try to see the news on the Start Page or trying to accessing the Extension Gallery or the NuGet Packages, I just always get an error like:

```
We are unable to download content due to network issues
```

on the start page. And via NuGet I get this error:

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I tried to add the config lines to the devenv.exe.config but I didn't work for me. I added the tags mentioned here: [Cannot connect to any online resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859148/cannot-connect-to-any-online-resource)

Only when I try to connect to the Visual Studio Gallery I get a different message:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it <ip>
```

The internal browser of VS is working. IE8 is working as well.

**Edit:** I solved the problem due to adding a different proxy server. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another problem with NuGet could be solved through adding the proxy settings directly to the NuGet config file. Now it's really working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

> 1. Uninstall NuGet
> 2. Restart Visual Studio
> 3. Install Nuget

You are set to go.

Comment: As I said I can't access the VS Gallery to reinstall it. I tried the earlier.

Comment: @Zumarta You can't access Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Nuget Package Manager?

Comment: I can access the installed tools, but when I uninstall it and want to reinstall it via the Online gallery, I can't access the gallery.

Comment: Really strange! Is the server accessing the Internet behind a proxy?

Comment: I guess it is, the LAN settings were detected automatically. Unfortunately I don't have further details about the proxy, otherwise I've tried to add the proxy URL into the config file to connect to.